# Mysql - search over multiple tables

Tags: mysql, left-join, union

i want to perform a simple search over multiple tables
and receive the search hit and some additional informations

---

**my database-schema**

- table1: |id|entry1|entry2|entry3|
- table2: |id|entry1|entry2|entry3|
- table3: |id|entry1|entry2|entry3|
- table4: |id|entry1|entry2|entry3|
- table5: |id|entry1|entry2|entry3|

(the ID-columns are foreign keys to a different table and the entries are varchars)

---

lets say table1 contains (1,'abc','def','ghi')

and table2 contains (1,'test','','')

searching with 'test' should return something like
'test','abc','def','ghi'

---

**option 1:**

joining all tables and select the right rows

```
Select * from
   big_Table_with_all_ID as t0
   /* mysql does not support FULL JOIN. we avoid this with LEFT-JOINS on 
   a table containing all IDs. Not exactly the same */
left join
   table1 as t1
on t0.id = t1.id

left join
   table2 as t2
on t0.id = t2.id
[...]
left join
   table5 as t5
on t0.id = t5.id

where t1.entry1 like '%search%' or 
      t1.entry2 like '%search%' or
      [...]
      t5.entry3 like '%search%'
```

this does not 'mark' the search-hit (could be done by client) 
should be the worst option, since joining too much data and including
to much information in the output

**option 2: adding subqueries**

joining 'filtered' tables

```
Select * from
   big_Table_with_all_ID as t0
left join
   (Select id,entry1 from table1 where entry1 like '%search%') as t1
on t0.id = t1.id

left join
   (Select id,entry2 from table1 where entry2 like '%search%') as t2
on t0.id = t2.id
[...]
left join
   (Select id,entry3 from table5 where entry3 like '%search%') as t15
on t0.id = t15.id

left join
   table1
on t0.id = table1.id;
```

output:

```
ID|table1        |table2          |...|table1           |
1 |NULL|NULL|NULL|'test'|NULL|NULL|...|'abc'|'dfg'|'ghi'|
```

will contain every ID even without a search-hit (only NULL-values)
(could be solved with adding the where clause from option1)

**option 3: UNION**

UNION 'filtered' tables and join with additional data

```
Select hit,entry1,entry2,entry3 from
(
   Select * from
      (
         Select id,entry1 as hit from table1 where entry1 like '%search%'
         UNION
         Select id,entry2 as hit from table1 where entry2 like '%search%'
         [...]
         UNION
         Select id,entry3 as hit from table5 where entry3 like '%search%'
      ) as tmp
      group by id  
) as tmp
left join
   table1
on tmp.id = table1.id
where hit is not null
```

output:

```
hit   |entry1|entry2|entry3
'test'|'abc' |'def' |'ghi'
```

contains no unnecessary information

---

which option/alternative should i choose, for a 'good' performance
and readability?

Comment: If you do this kind of query frequently, you may want to change the whole design. Try create a combined table and use triggers to keep it updated.

Answer (score 0):

option 1 is not good because mysql can have issues joining many table, i would not use it. considering the fact the the result of your subquery are small (only 1 row), i think option 2 and 3 are similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a variation on the third method:

```
Select t1.*, entry1, entry2, entry3
from (Select id, max(entry1) as entry1,
             max(entry2) as entry2, max(entry3) as entry3
     from (Select id, entry1 as hit, NULL as entry2, NULL as entry3 from table1 where entry1 like '%search%'
           UNION ALL
           Select id, NULL, entry2 as hit, NULL from table2 where entry2 like '%search%'
           [...]
           UNION ALL
           Select id, NULL, NULL, entry3 as hit from table5 where entry3 like '%search%'
          ) as tmp
     group py id  
    ) as tmp join
    table1 t1
    on tmp.id = t1.id;
```

Some comments:

- You want to use `union all` rather than `union` to avoid unnecessary duplicate elimination.
- Do not use `select *` with `group by`.  The results are indeterminate.
- Although it doesn't matter in this case (because the `like` has a wildcard at the beginning), the separate queries can each take advantage of an index, if appropriate.
- I don't understand the mapping between the three entries and the five tables, but this query follows your structure.
- I don't know what `hit is not null` is supposed to do.  I think a `join` captures the right logic.

Comment: the problem is, the the real tables are not that equal, saying they differ in the number of columns. (should have mentioned it).